# Can't prevent form from automatically submitting twice after a click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

The first time I submits a from triggers a duplicate submission but subsequent ones only happen once.

I have used the preventDefault() method but still gets submitted twice at first instance but subsequent ones only submit once.

The Form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'verify_form']); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Identity Type <span class="error">*</span></label>
            <?php echo $form->field($identitiesModel, 'type')->dropDownList($identitiesModel->identityTypes(), [
                'prompt' => 'Select an identity',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => true
            ])->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Identification Number <span class="error">*</span></label>
            <?php echo $form->field($identitiesModel, 'identificationId')->textInput([
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => true
            ])->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last name <span class="error">*</span></label>
            <?php echo $form->field($identitiesModel, 'lastname')->textInput([
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder'=> 'Last name',
                'required' => true
            ])->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First name <span class="error">*</span></label>
            <?php echo $form->field($identitiesModel, 'firstname')->textInput([
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder'=> 'First name',
                'required' => true
            ])->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Date of Birth <span class="error">*</span></label>
            <?php echo $form->field($identitiesModel, 'date_of_birth')->widget(DatePicker::className([
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Select date of birth',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'format' => 'Y-m-d',
                    'todayHighlight' => true,
                ]
            ]))->label(false) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success subBtn">Search</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default clearBtn">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>


JS Code
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#verify_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()

        $('.otherResult').empty();
        let x = $('#verify_form #verificationform-date_of_birth').val();
        if(x.length == 0){
            swalFunc('info','Oops...','Date of birth must be filled');
            return false;
        } 

        $('#verify_form .subBtn').attr('disabled', true);
        let formValues = $(this).serialize();        
            let link = '".Url::toRoute("api/verification-search")."';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: link,
                data: formValues,
                beforeSend: function(){           
                   $('.loadImage').css({'display': 'block'}); 
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#verify_form .subBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                    socket.emit('identity', data);
                },
                complete:function(){
                    $('.loadImage').css({'display': 'none'});
                }  
            });
            return false;
    });
})
```

I'd expected that the ajax call to be invoked once every time the submit button is triggered but the code above submits twice at first instance even though the submit button was clicked once and this results to having duplicate records.

Comment: I can't see how it submits even once with that `return false` in there

Comment: I wonder, does `ActiveForm::` put any JS code in the page?

Comment: The ActiveForm (Yii2 ActiveForm) is equivalent to the form tag in Html... I added the Js Code myself

Comment: @JaromandaX, sorry I have edited my code. The initial return false was when I was testing before it gets to the ajax call.

Comment: if you put a `console.log` at the top of the submit function, is it called twice? if you make it a `console.trace()` you may be able to see something useful

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes it called twice for the first click on the submit button but subsequently, it only calls once.

Comment: and does the `console.trace` show anything interesting?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.unbind('submit')` before the `.submit`?

Comment: Try `ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'verify_form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => false]);`. I believe i've encountered simillar problem and the ajax validation was the culprit.

Comment: why are you using `.submit` whereas you should use the event provided by the `ActiveForm` i.e `.on('beforeSubmit',function(){})` event

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just disable the button with jquery after submit.

try

```
$('form').submit(function() {
$(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: For some weird and unknown reasons, this didn't work for me.

Comment: It would be better to test the ajax validation not on submit but on field change. remember that you can then test on the controller if it is an ajax call or post call.
The problem you are facing is because its sending the fields every time you change the.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was firing twice was because there was multiple forms render in tabs. So the code below solved my problem with few logics

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    let x = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    console.log(x);
    return false;
});
```